# How to use text user input in pygame using a Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, module, pygame

I need to know how to download and set up a module on a mac.

I also need to know how to use text user input with pygame on a Mac. Just like `raw_input` but with pygame.

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Welcome to pygame. You have to build this all yourself. You will need to monitor keypresses using events and use that to find what a user is typing.
That, or, find one someone has already made on the internet and download the code.

Comment: wow seems so time consuming. i figured their was a more efficient way.

Comment: Well, I guess you're meant to enjoy it :P

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a comment but my reputation is to low
I don't know is there something different on Mac but in Windows you use:

```
   import nameofmodule
```

for text input you could use Tkinter or some other GUI or maybe pygame Inputbox or EzText however GUI-es sometimes don't work after compilation so you'll need some debugging and Inputbox and EzText doesn't look very nice and have some bugs(to close Inputbox you must press pygame x button what confuses user).I would suggest to use Tkinter and fight with compilation errors as it's easier(at least to me) then trying to debug Inputbox or someone's work especially if you don't want to compile it.

Please correct me if I'm wrong about Inputbox that's whathappend to me.